# Can i adjust the height of the day view in FullCalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to restyle a instance of FullCalendar so that the day and week views run the entire height of the web page. i.e. I do not want a scrollbar to view the entire day. I tried removing overflow and the fixed height but that doesn’t work.
Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the slotMinutes when creating the chart http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/slotMinutes/

and then you can adjust the content height to fit it all in there with this
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/contentHeight/