# Fullcalendar jquery plugin height issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I integrated fullcalendar within a webpage but for some reason, the height I applied through the 'height' property available within the plugin only works for MonthView.

The code:

```
var calendarOptions = {
                theme: true,
                defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                allDaySlot: false,
                allDayText: 'all-day',                
                height: ($(window).height()) - ($("div.calendarTitle").offset().top),
                firstHour: 7,
                firstDay: 1,
                slotMinutes: 30,
                defaultEventMinutes: 120,
                axisFormat: 'H:mm',
                .....
```

Basically, the `($(window).height()) - ($("div.calendarTitle").offset().top)` is intended to cover the given area.

I would like to know whether anybody else experienced this issue or has any idea about how I can overcome it. All I want is to get the same height, regardless of month view, day view or week view.

Right now, week and day view cover 70% of the page.

Comment: Are you changing the aspect ratio?  It has been a while since I have used it, but I seem to recall that you may need to adjust the ratio.

Comment: aspectRatio in my example was 5, because I tried to change it to see what's happening. I tried playing with it but to no avail..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried dynamically setting it after initialization?

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'height', 700);
```

[FullCalendar Documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/height/)

Another approach (for DayView) is provided in [*this question's answers*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508903/can-i-adjust-the-height-of-the-day-view-in-fullcalendar) on stack.

You can also try an approach like [*this*](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=260) (the last entry) for WeekView.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input. I just tried that after the initialization but somehow it won't go more than 771 pixels for Day and Week view. I cannot make it larger than that. I can only make MonthView larger than 771.

Comment: What is the pixel width of the page?

Comment: The page is made of two panels, a fixed one on the right(20% of width) and a fluid one(remaining), which is the content div. The calendar covers the entire width of the content div.

Comment: I was just wondering if the width of that div and the set aspect ratio are preventing the height from growing over 771.  How tall is it if you don't dynamically set it after initialization?

Comment: I will be adding FullCalendar to another project in the next several months, so please let me know if one of the approaches works for you.

Comment: I tried but to no avail. After more research, I found that only if I overwrite styles with javascript I can turn it in what I want.
Either that or change the minute slots property (currently is per half hour). 
Javascript overwriting creates another bug though, when adding events...